# how read two records at once from sql select query results?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to read two records each time from select query results in PHP ?

Comment: yes, but how to access the index of the results if i use @mysql_fetch_assoc   ??

Comment: In my opinion, You must go through tutorial before asking this type of basic questions. They are covered well there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  // Do something
}
```

EDIT:

Then it would be like this

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  // Do something
  $row1 = $row2
}
```

Comment: i want to do somthing with each twic recodes .. like this .. 1 with 2, 2 with 3, 3 with 4 ... but this let me 1 with 2 , 3 with 4, ..

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in comment:

> i want to do somthing with each twic
>   recodes .. like this .. 1 with 2, 2
>   with 3, 3 with 4 ... but this let me 1
>   with 2 , 3 with 4, ..

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row1 != false){
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);)
   {
     // do something

      $row1 = $row2 ;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_query engine for PHP only supports single queries. You'll need to execute each query separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think, UNION can help you. It would fetch you the two records in a single query execution.